XRDP terminates after 90 seconds when rebooting
I'm running a Debian with KDE as a Server and XRDP terminates after every reboot after exactly 90 seconds. What I gathered so far is that it seems to reach a time limit for some reason.
I have already spent hours into this reading varous posts on different forums but none of the solutions there have worked out for me. I even went as far as reinstalling the OS and started from scratch, but the same problem occurs.
Now, what's really weird is that if I start XRDP manually after it failed, it just works perfectly. Until I reboot and the circle repeats.
sudo systemctl status xrdp
× xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2024-10-22 20:39:57 CEST; 46s ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
        CPU: 15ms


Okt 22 20:38:27 debian-srv xrdp[841]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Okt 22 20:38:27 debian-srv systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: No such>
Okt 22 20:38:29 debian-srv xrdp[853]: [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 853
Okt 22 20:38:29 debian-srv xrdp[853]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Okt 22 20:38:29 debian-srv xrdp[853]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Okt 22 20:38:29 debian-srv xrdp[853]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Okt 22 20:39:57 debian-srv systemd[1]: xrdp.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Okt 22 20:39:57 debian-srv xrdp[853]: [INFO ] Received termination signal, stopping the server accept new connections t>
Okt 22 20:39:57 debian-srv systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Okt 22 20:39:57 debian-srv systemd[1]: Stopped xrdp.service - xrdp daemon.

sudo nano /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
[20241022-20:37:50] [WARN ] Window manager (pid 1376, display 10) exited with non-zero exit code 255 and signal 15. Thi>[20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] Calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 1357                                        [20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] Terminating X server (pid 1377) on display 10
[20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] Terminating the xrdp channel server (pid 1422) on display 10                                [20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] X server on display 10 (pid 1377) returned exit code 0 and signal number 0                  [20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] xrdp channel server for display 10 (pid 1422) exit code 255 and signal number 1
[20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] cleanup_sockets:                                                                            [20241022-20:37:50] [INFO ] sesman_main_loop: sesman asked to terminate                                                 [20241022-20:38:27] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 816
[20241022-20:39:57] [INFO ] sesman_main_loop: sesman asked to terminate

System:
Lenovo M720q Tiny
Intel Core i5-8500T
16GB RAM
512GB M.2 NVMe

I just discovered that if I reboot the computer trough xrdp, everything works. Only if I reboot trough ssh terminal, xrdp fails to start. No idea why, but I honestly don't care anymore
